# Get data from MySQL using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to take an input (date) from a form in a php file, and use the date variable to select data from a mysql database and return an array in the same php file without refreshing the page. Right now, I have 3 files: `index.php`, `global.js`, and `date.php`

`index.php` takes an input (a date, in this case)

```
Date: <input type="text" id="date">
  <input type="submit" id="date-submit" value="Submit">
  <div id="date-data"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
```

`global.js` listens for a click on the submit button and posts the input (date) to `date.php`

```
$('input#date-submit').on('click', function() {
    var date = $('input#date').val();
    $.post('../ajax/date.php', {date: date}, function(data) {
        $('div#date-data').html(data);
        alert(data);
    });

});
```

`date.php` takes the date and queries the mysql database to return an array. This array needs to be passed back to `index.php` but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
<?php 

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('gymflow', $con);
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` = $date");
    $values = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $values[] = $row['utilization'];
  }
echo json_encode($values);

?>
```

Ideally, I need to be able to have the `$values` variable from `date.php` passed to a `$values` variable in `index.php`

There must be an easier way to do this...

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and will be deprecated for good in PHP 5.5. Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Comment: The way you get back the output of `data.php` in `index.php` is by the AJAX callback. That will update the page. What are you asking for?

Comment: what do u get in values[] array..??

Comment: It returns a blank array...i think this is because of some problem with syntax in `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM past_traffic WHERE 'date' = $date");` because when i hard code the date, i get an array with data. The 2nd problem is I don't know how to get this array into a variable in the callback...right now I just have it printed inside a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of your AJAX call is to not refresh `index.php`, and instead deliver the result of `data.php` straight into the first page. You can modify the DOM via the javascript callback, and should make other database-requests in `data.php`. There is no purpose in letting `index.php` aware of the output of `data.php`, simply because when the Javascript call is made, your first page has already been processed and sent to the client and possibly already rendered in the browser window.

If you need to know the input value in subsequent requests to `index.php` you may store in the value in the user's session.

Comment: I can get the array printed inside the div, but I want to be able to use it as a variable $values in index.php. After the callback, I need $values to exist in index.php because I call a include a separate php file that draws a css graph based on the $values array.

Comment: That is just the point, you can not include the $values variable in index.php because it never exists. However since you do manage to get the required data from the callback you can use javascript to manipulate the database extracts and draw the css graph. You can not use php

Comment: Is there any way to save the date input in index.php to a variable in the same file?

Comment: No, but you can store it in the session scope. Be aware that the lifecycle of a PHP script is a fraction of a second: as soon as the last line of your script is reached, it dies. So there's no way to set its variables, but you can use sessions (or database, or a file, or whatever) to persist input across multiple requests